# Magento - Splitting an order into 2

Tags: magento, split

I am trying to make a functionnality so that a customer will be able to split his order into 2, in case some articles are temporarily unavailable and if they wish that we send them part of their order first. So the idea is to create 2 new orders and cancelling the old one.

Do you have any idee about how to do this programmatically please ?

Comment: You can do multiple shipments on a single order.
Order splitting is possible, but it is overkill for what you want to do in my opinion. Order splitting is best suited for very complex situations at checkout time- such as splitting payments.

Comment: Base on what payment method you are using and if you are using credit card are you doing authorize or authorize and capture then technically you could do `Partial Invoice`

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing doesn't sound necessary... You're talking about sending part of the order first... Notice in the Magento Admin once an order is place you can create an invoice, take note that you do not have to invoice everything at one time, the same is true when you create a shipment. You'll need to make sure you're merchant / payment gateway supports multiple partial captures against a single authorization.

However, if you really want to split the orders in two, it is a rather complicated process. We've done it, and its very tricky... you need to modify the opcheckout.js file, you'll need to modify the template since you will have to create seperate shipping methods for each order. You'll need to modify the OnePage controller & Model files very significantly. There are tricky areas in terms of re-executing the totals and making sure data on the order and subsequent quote and address models is precisely what is required by Magento. Maintaining the other checkout functionality requires diligence, such as saving the customer's address when checking out. If you're really going down the path of coding something that splits an order into two orders during the checkout process, feel free to send me a message and we can talk more in-depth and I'll send you some code.